# retain the last object with same property in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array

```
const obj=[{fullCart: 5, halfCart: 4, smu: 3, stowage: 5, index: "FC-093"},
 {fullCart: 5, halfCart: 4, smu: 8, stowage: 5, index: "FC-093"},
 {fullCart: 5, halfCart: 4, smu: 0, stowage: 5, index: "FC-093"},
 {fullCart: 5, halfCart: 5, smu: 3, stowage: 5, index: "FC-093"},
 {fullCart: 5, halfCart: 7, smu: 3, stowage: 5, index: "FC-093"}
 ]
```

I need to retain the last object  in the array ie whichever is the previous object with same property here index:'FC-093' should be removed.  ie the result should be,

```
[{fullCart: 5, halfCart: 7, smu: 3, stowage: 5, index: "FC-093"}]
```

Comment: Does this mean that you have an array of objects where you can have multiple objects with different `index` key value? Add more clarity to your question plz and also we need to see your attempt

Comment: Are you looking to keep the last instance of each `index` value?  i.e. if there was another element in the array with `index: "FC-9999"` would the results array contain two elements?

Comment: pretty precise.no two occurrence should be there the latest one should only be retained.indexes may vary.In the end this array should have indexes which are various but shouldn't repeat

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you need.

1. You get every `unique` index value in an array using `.map()` method
2. You loop thru your `unique` array now and use the `findLast` method to get the last element in your `obj` array per value in your `unique` array and push it in your `result` array

```js
const obj=[
 {fullCart: 5, halfCart: 4, smu: 3, stowage: 5, index: "FC-093"},
 {fullCart: 5, halfCart: 4, smu: 8, stowage: 5, index: "FC-093"},
 {fullCart: 5, halfCart: 4, smu: 0, stowage: 5, index: "FC-093"},
 {fullCart: 5, halfCart: 5, smu: 3, stowage: 5, index: "FC-093"},
 {fullCart: 10, halfCart: 7, smu: 3, stowage: 5, index: "FC-093"},
 {fullCart: 3, halfCart: 6, smu: 4, stowage: 5, index: "FC-095"},
 {fullCart: 3, halfCart: 6, smu: 5, stowage: 5, index: "FC-095"},
 {fullCart: 10, halfCart: 7, smu: 8, stowage: 5, index: "FC-095"},
 {fullCart: 2, halfCart: 8, smu: 10, stowage: 5, index: "FC-098"},
 {fullCart: 10, halfCart: 9, smu: 2, stowage: 5, index: "FC-098"}
];
let result = [];//initialize result array

//create unique array
const unique = [...new Set(obj.map(item => item.index))];
console.log(unique)//prints every unique value from key index found in an array 

//loop thru unique array
unique.forEach(ele => {
  //find last element where index value is present in unique array
  let res = obj.findLast((element) => element.index == ele);
  result.push(res)
})

console.log(result)//expected output
```

Answer (score 0):

This loops through all elements only keeping the last element with a given id.

```
const result = Object.values(obj.reduce((acc, el) => {
  acc[el.index] = el;
  return acc;
}, {}));
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not entirely sure I fully understand your question. If you simply want to return the last entry you can do:

```
    function returnLast(arr) {
        let index = arr.length - 1;
        return arr[index];
    }
```

If you wanted to remove that last entry then you could make a new array and set the old one equal to the new one:

```
let array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

function makeNewArray(arr) {
    return arr.slice(0, -1);
}

array = makeNewArray(array);
// array == [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: no two occurrence should be there the latest object with an index should only be retained.indexes may vary.In the end this array should have indexes which are various but shouldn't repeat and the latest object with an index should only exist